# Make youtube-dl wait until a live stream starts

Tags: youtube, youtube-dl

Using `youtube-dl`, you can easily download an **ongoing** live streaming.

```sh
$ youtube-dl --hls-use-mpegts <URL>
```

If the target live stream hasn't been started yet, however, the command exits right away after printing messages like

```
[youtube] I1gi2ABCDEf: Downloading webpage
ERROR: This live event will begin in a few moments.
```

Is it possible to make `youtube-dl` wait until the live stream starts and then record it?

My current workaround is this:

```sh
#pseudo code
while (true) {
    start = time()
    execute youtube-dl
    end = time()
    if (end - start > 10seconds) { #if recording succeeded
        break
    }
    sleep(some seconds)
}
```

or this:

```sh
#pseudo code
while (true) {
    if (check_if_live_is_active_using_curl_or_youtube_api()) {
        break
    }
    sleep(some seconds)
}
execute youtube-dl
```

Combining the both is working perfectly now (actualy the second one should be enough but I use also the first one as a fallback) but it would be nice if there was a more elegant way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [2023 update]

**[yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp)** (youtube-dl fork) has this feature, using `--wait-for-video <seconds>` option. Version `2023.01.02` or newer is required.

Example:

```bash
yt-dlp --wait-for-video 10 https://www.twitch.tv/team_julienrqt
```

This will check every 10 seconds whether a stream is active, and download the stream.

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to be on a linux distro with systemd, you can use systemd-run to schedule a transient timer unit. For example, if the stream starts at 3:30:

```
systemd-run --working-directory=/path/to/save/file --on-calendar=15:30 youtube-dl --hls-use-mpegts <URL>
```

You could add the options `--property Restart=on-failure` and `--property RestartSec=30` to retry if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will do

```
until youtube-dl --hls-use-mpegts <URL>; do continue; done
```

or another alternative

```
while [[ true ]]; do youtube-dl --hls-use-mpegts && break || continue ; done
```

But there is no in-built function if you were looking for that.
Best approach would be the one you already did by using a script or the command line workarounds.